# Python "IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars'"

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib

NOTE: the first part of "code" isn't code, it's error message from terminal, SE made me format it that way.

Linux machine using Python 2.7.6

I have download automator which is supposed to take clipboard contents (this works) and download them (this doesn't work). Here is error message:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/thomasshera/Create polynomial from random sequence.py", line 6, in <module>

urllib.urlretrieve(text_in_clipboard, "/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve

return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 244, in retrieve
tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars'
```

Here is code:

```python
import Tkinter
import urllib
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() # Hide the main window (optional)
text_in_clipboard = root.clipboard_get()
urllib.urlretrieve(text_in_clipboard, "/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars")
```

This would be straightforward to fix using Python shell except that there is no line 94 of my program- the shell is somehow wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second parameter of `urlretrieve` should be a path to a file not to a directory.

> **[urllib.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])**
>
> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary.

You may fix it like:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(text_in_clipboard, "/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars/download.temp")
```

Comment: What error  you had?

Comment: See above, thanks! (Downvote because it doesn't work, comment still helpful.)

Comment: @ThomasShera where above? impossible to have the same error "is a  directory" and this answer is the same idea as the other answers

Comment: See above, took a while to add because SE requires me to format most of it as code.

Comment: @ThomasShera I understand that the first problem is being fixed and another problem is discovered. In this case, my answer is valid, and you should ask the new problem as independent question.

Comment: good point, doing that.

Comment: @ThomasShera please consider to reverse the downvote, I edited the post.

Comment: I can't for 16 minutes, will then.

Answer (score 1):

Error occurs not in your code, but in the library you use - so why you see line 94 of file /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py. But the reason of it is in yours code. `urllib.urlretrieve` takes filename (not folder name) as its second argument. (In traceback we see that it is passed to function `open` which expects filename). This will work:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(text_in_clipboard, "/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars/data.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, the error you see has nothing to do with line 94 of your script, rather it's in `urllib.py` module.

Secondly, the problem is how you are using `urlretrieve` method. It takes in an URL and a filename. But you're using path to a directory, rather than a file. And `urllib` tells you exactly what I just said:

```
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/thomasshera/Pictures/Star Wars'
```

Please, read [urllib docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) carefully.